# Reassigning text in HTML using js gives error

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to reassign the text in mark tag but everytime i run it its only changing one tag and gives an error

```
  let a = document.getElementsByTagName("mark").length;
  
  for(i=0;i<=a;i++){
    let b = document.getElementsByTagName("mark")[i];
    let c = document.getElementsByTagName("mark")[i].innerText ="AWESOME";
  }
```

Error Message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')
    at Change (index.js:8:64)
    at index.js:20:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to change your for loop:
`for(i=0;i<=a;i++)`to `for(i=0;i<a;i++)`, because you are starting from 0.

Comment: Thank you :), funny how i didn't notice that

Comment: Haha it happens. Good job!

Comment: @Zaynekomichi I'll be happy if you accept this as the answer.

Comment: sorry about that hadn't used stackoverflow in a while

Answer (score -1):

```js
let a = document.getElementsByTagName("mark").length;
  
  for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    let b = document.getElementsByTagName("mark")[i];
    b.innerText ="AWESOME";
  }
```

```html
<mark></mark>
<mark></mark>
<mark></mark>
<mark></mark>
```

Just changed the condition of for loop from `i<=a` to `i<a`

Explaination:-
The error comes because after every tag is iterated, for loop runs again when it finds no tag and `b = undefined` and it gives the error

Thank you.